# Let's tweak question lists to show which questions have an accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, search, accepted-answer, question-lists

In question lists and search results, instead of just seeing that a question has *n* votes and *n* answers, wouldn't it be handy to know whether it has an accepted answer too? This wouldn't even need to take up column width; for example, we could show the answer count with no background when there's no accepted answer, and green background (or green tick background) when there is one.

Comment: That already happens. On what site do you not see a difference? (Or on what page exactly?)

Comment: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) opening page. Questions with any answers have green background, whether or not they have an accepted answer. Ditto questions in search results from that page.

Comment: Questions with an accepted answer have the number of answers in yellow. Questions without an accepted answer have the number of answers in white. You could argue that there is not enough visual difference, but that should be done on Stack Overflow's meta since the styling is different on every site.

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty obvious now I know (= too subtle IMHO, so I may take it up on meta SO ...or buy a new monitor, or visit the optician!).

Answer (score 0):

It is already implemented.

**Stack Overflow**:

- No answers:

[image]

- 1 answer:

[image]

- 1 answer, accepted:

[image]

**Server Fault**:

- No answers:

[image]

- 1 answer:

[image]

- 1 answer, accepted:

[image]